# Localhost fails to display images

Tags: python, image, localhost, cgi-bin

I am attempting to display an image on `localhost`. As a first step, I have created a sever script in python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import BaseHTTPServer
import CGIHTTPServer
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()  ## This line enables CGI error reporting

server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 8000)
handler.cgi_directories = ["/"]

httpd = server(server_address, handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

The image is placed within the same directory where this script is executing. 
Subsequently `http://localhost:8000/test.jpg` is typed in the browser.

The browser fails to render the image with an error:
`The image "http://localhost:8000/test.jpg" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.`

The server script throws an error like

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/CGIHTTPServer.py", line 253, in run_cgi
    os.execve(scriptfile, args, env)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

I have tried displaying text and the server works fine with lot of examples. Except that it fails to load images. Where am I going wrong?

---

The problem was solved. I moved the test.jpg into a sub-directory within the 
server directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is attempting to execute the test.jpg as a cgi script. If you remove the CGIHttpRequestHandler and instead use SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler you will get your image back. If you need both, then you need to put the image somewhere else.

Comment: I definitely need to display the image, along with few texts messages on the html. The image is generated after the execution of a python script, which thus requires CGIHttpServer. How to handle this situation? The SimpleHTTP displays the image on browser, but I need CGIHttp to generate it on the first hand.

Comment: Put the CGI script inside a subdirectory and serve it from there? By default it looks like if you put it in cgi-bin it will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

CGI is used to execute server-side scripts, not to serve static content. It will therefore attempt to execute files that are being served (in this case, attempting to execute an image): `os.execve(scriptfile, args, env)`.

Execution is equivalent to running the file at your shell.

Use [`SimpleHTTPServer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) for static content, such as images.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is because you have no html page setup.

Your python script although is running a server on your localhost, but you need html/css pages
to actually display pictures and words.

Comment: I do create a html page, and display text. The test.jpg is locally there, but does not render on browser.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but to simply display the image, you have to embed it in your html code with an image tag.<img src="test.jpg" alt="test image">